# GET /static/css/style.css?after HTTP/1.1 404 1820

Tags: python, html, css, django, visual-studio-code

During python web development using django, the contents of static are not applied.. Is there a way? Below is the code

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIR = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static',
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/css'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/image'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/javascript'),
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

results are the same, and at the same time

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/css/style.css' %}?after" />
```

and other than

```
?after
```

output the same error

[image: this is errors]

My folder structure:

[image: my tree]

It is a situation where the codes of css were applied temporarily using the style tag of html.

The code below is urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from home import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings


app_name = 'home'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.main_home, name='main_home'),
    path('search/', views.dbSearch, name='search'),
    path('recipe/', views.apiSearch, name='recipe'),
    path('recipe/detail/', views.foodDetail, name='detail'),
    path('kakao/', views.kakaoLogin, name='login'),
    path('kakao/callback/', views.KakaoCallbackView.as_view(), name='kakao_callback')
    #    path('logIn', views.logIn),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: Can you post the snapshot of your project's root directory and files?

Comment: I also updated my root directory status. I tried putting the css file in the current template for the experiment, but it failed...

Comment: Note, you have two `STATIC_URL` and missing `STATIC_ROOT` option.

Comment: `STATICFILES_DIR` looks misused to me. Remove this block and set `STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'`.

Comment: And please show your urls.py file.

Comment: I Updated my url.py.  Correcting STATIC_URL, STATIC_ROOT, STATICFILES_DIRS results in the same error

Comment: `app_name = 'home'` I see only one urls.py in your project and it should not have app_name since it's the main urls.py. Move all urls relatede to `home` app to separate urls.py inside `home` subfolder and move `app_name = 'home'` there as well. Include this urls.py in your main urls.py. Leave `urlpatterns += static` in the main urls.py. And ensure that `settings.DEBUG=true`